# How to check isEmpty in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, is-empty

I want to check the `response.data.totalRows` is empty.

```
if (response!=undefined
   && response.data!=undefined
   && response.data.totalRows!=undefined) {

  alert(response.data.totalRows);
}
```

Can simplify the code?

UPDATE: it seems that there is no simple method like `isEmpty(response.data.totalRows)`.

Comment: to check empty you can use: `if(response.data.totalRows=="")`

Comment: not if you are not sure about the presents of those keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea, you can simply do this:

```
if (response && response.data && response.data.totalRows) {
    alert(response.data.totalRows);
}
```

In JavaScript, a object is cast to a `truthy` value, when used in a `if`. This means you can just "dump" the variable in a `if` or any other boolean statement, as a check to see whether or not it exists. [this blog post](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) has some more information about it.

Please note that this will *not*  alert anything if `totalRows` equals `0` (since `0` is considered a `falsy` value.) If you also want to alert if it's `0`, use this:

```
if (response && response.data &&
    (response.data.totalRows || response.data.totalRows === 0)) {
    alert(response.data.totalRows);
}
```

Or:

```
if (response && response.data && response.data.totalRows !== undefined) {
    alert(response.data.totalRows);
}
```

Comment: Not right, if `response.data.totalRows` is 0 it is resolved to false.

Comment: The last point due to `precedence` but only if all `keys` (+1 for Arun P Johny) are set http://jsfiddle.net/2e4CZ/ (had the same idea, just saw you did it already;)

Comment: +1 Update: Works too http://jsfiddle.net/2e4CZ/1/ (without set keys). My bad sir. Should be accepted answer, huh?

Comment: Could the person that downvoted this answer please explain why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a prototype (even if it's not recommended)

```
Object.prototype.isEmpty = function(){
  return (!this || this===undefined || this===null || !this.hasChildNodes())
    ?true
    :false;
}
```

And then just use

```
if(!response.isEmpty()) alert(response.data.totalRows);
```

It is only handy if you need the checks also elsewhere and not only one place.

Comment: You know, `this==undefined` and `this==null` are pretty much the same.

Comment: I think it is handy even if you only use it in one place. Makes it easier to read the code..

Comment: Thanks Cerbrus for your comment but I must say here, that there is a small difference between those two. Where undefined says that the variable has been declared but not set yet and null means, that the variable doesn't exist yet. But you are correct, that it wasn't needed for this example. I just like to check everything everytime.

Comment: In your case, you probably want to check for type & value, then: `===`, because with `==`, the twot are functionally identical.

Comment: What Cerbrus is saying is that `null == undefined` is true therefore `this==undefined` and `this==null` are the same. `==` is not the same as `===`.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `response.data.totalRows` must be an array you can use just:

```
if (!response.data.totalRows.length) {
   /* empty array */
}
```

If you are not sure that `totalRows` exists you must verify:

```
if (
   !response ||
   !response.data ||
   !response.data.totalRows ||
   !response.data.totalRows.length
) {
   /* is empty */
}
```

Any value is converted in `Boolean`. For example: `Boolean(response)` will return false if `response` will be `0`, `null`, `undefined` etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about a try-catch block?

```
try{ alert(response.data.totalRows); }
catch(e) { alert("undefined"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
response && response.data && response.data.totalRows && alert(response.data.totalRows)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the property list gets very long there is another syntax you can use, in the sample code I've created a function so it can be re used.

```
// args is { object: the object to check the properties of
//           properties: an array of strings with property names}
function isSet(args){
  //no checking of arguments
  var o = args.object,
  props = args.properties,
  i = -1,len = props.length
  while(typeof o !== "undefined"
    && o !== null
    && ++i<len){
    o = o[props[i]];
  }
  return (typeof o !== "undefined" 
    && o !== null)?true:false;
}
var test = {
  prop1 : {
    prop2 : "ok"
  }
};
//check if test.prop1.prop2 is set
console.log(isSet({
  object:test,
  properties: ["prop1","prop2"]
}));//=true
```